# Dependencies in AngularJs and factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, object-literal

I just got started with AngularJS, and I just got a couple of questions that hopefully you can help me figure them out.

Having (as an example) the following `js` folder structure:

```
+---admin
|   |   ai-constants.js
|   |   commons.js
|   |   
|   +---modules
|   |       searcher.js
|   |
```

`constants.js` is that a file that I'm trying to use it as a dependency in `searcher.js`, and here is its content:

```
var aiConstants = angular.module("aiConstants", []);

aiConstants.factory("user", function () {
    return {
        ahaha: 0,
    }
});

aiConstants.factory("tagCategory", function () {
    return {
        none: 0,
        artisticMovement: 1,
        technicalMaterials: 2,
        art: 3,
        organizations: 4,
        professionals: 5,
    }
});
```

And here's the some of the content of `searcher.js`

```
var app = angular.module('searcher', ['tagCategory']);

app.controller('SearcherController', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/api/search/tags/'+tagCategory.art).success(function(data) {
        $scope.tiposDeArte = data;
    });
```

To test if it works, I tried loading the `js` files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin/ai-constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin/modules/searcher.js"></script>
```

But, no go! So I was wondering:

1. Am I doing it correctly?
2. Is there a way of loading a `js` file as dependency (mostly will contain literal objects) from a path?

### Update

The error I get is:

> Uncaught Error: No module: tagCategory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `searcher` module needs a dependency defined for the `aiConstants` *module*. Then you can inject services from that module where you need to. So, it would look something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('searcher', ['aiConstants']);

app.controller('SearcherController', function($scope, $http, tagCategory) {

    $http.get('/api/search/tags/'+tagCategory.art).success(function(data) {
        $scope.tiposDeArte = data;
    });
```

Comment: Hehe, I was just doing that right now, and it worked... but thank you for your answer. However, besides the `2.` remaining questing, I have this other: Is there no other way of including dependencies then just doing `...$http, tagCategory, user, AnotherDependency, ...) {` ?

Comment: You probably want to read this: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di. Hopefully that will answer all the questions you have about Dependency Injection in Angular.